# how to display specific data from sub-array using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

hello guys im confused and don't have more idea, how to append specific json string to select tag from sub-array. i have already searched over the internet but some answer and problem didn't match my issue.

```
array (size=6)
  0 => 
    array (size=16)
      'id' => int 7
      'receive_purchase_series_id' => null
      'lumber_processing_series_id' => int 174
      'items_series_code' => string 'LP-001-id_1-001-001' (length=19)
      'quantity' => int 50
      'type_id' => int 7
      'supplier_id' => null
      'status' => int 0
      'created_by_id' => int 49
      'scanned_by_id' => int 49
      'receive_purchase_code_from' => null
      'lumber_processing_code_from' => string '191589764523' (length=12)
      'item_id' => int 40
      'created_at' => string '2017-06-30 08:40:17' (length=19)
      'updated_at' => string '2017-06-30 08:40:17' (length=19)
      'nail_items' => 
        array (size=6)
          'id' => int 40
          'type_id' => int 7
          'code' => string 'LI-7' (length=4)
          'description' => string '90X120X200' (length=10)
          'created_at' => string '2017-05-15 11:29:12' (length=19)
          'updated_at' => string '2017-05-15 11:29:12' (length=19)
  1 => 
    array (size=16)
      'id' => int 8
      'receive_purchase_series_id' => null
      'lumber_processing_series_id' => int 175
      'items_series_code' => string 'LP-001-id_1-001-002' (length=19)
      'quantity' => int 50
      'type_id' => int 7
      'supplier_id' => null
      'status' => int 0
      'created_by_id' => int 49
      'scanned_by_id' => int 49
      'receive_purchase_code_from' => null
      'lumber_processing_code_from' => string '191589764523' (length=12)
      'item_id' => int 40
      'created_at' => string '2017-07-03 08:57:47' (length=19)
      'updated_at' => string '2017-07-03 08:57:47' (length=19)
      'nail_items' => 
        array (size=6)
          'id' => int 40
          'type_id' => int 7
          'code' => string 'LI-7' (length=4)
          'description' => string '90X120X200' (length=10)
          'created_at' => string '2017-05-15 11:29:12' (length=19)
          'updated_at' => string '2017-05-15 11:29:12' (length=19)
  2 => 
    array (size=16)
      'id' => int 9
      'receive_purchase_series_id' => null
      'lumber_processing_series_id' => int 176
      'items_series_code' => string 'LP-001-id_1-002-001' (length=19)
      'quantity' => int 60
      'type_id' => int 8
      'supplier_id' => null
      'status' => int 0
      'created_by_id' => int 49
      'scanned_by_id' => int 49
      'receive_purchase_code_from' => null
      'lumber_processing_code_from' => string '430159790249' (length=12)
      'item_id' => int 38
      'created_at' => string '2017-07-03 09:01:23' (length=19)
      'updated_at' => string '2017-07-03 09:01:23' (length=19)
      'nail_items' => 
        array (size=6)
          'id' => int 38
          'type_id' => int 8
          'code' => string 'LI-5' (length=4)
          'description' => string '18X127X1000' (length=11)
          'created_at' => string '2017-05-09 16:41:39' (length=19)
          'updated_at' => string '2017-05-15 10:37:13' (length=19)
  3 => 
    array (size=4)
      'nail_id' => int 27
      'code' => string 'NI-1' (length=4)
      'description' => string 'NAIL ITEM 1' (length=11)
      'type' => null
  4 => 
    array (size=4)
      'nail_id' => int 28
      'code' => string 'NI-2' (length=4)
      'description' => string 'NAIL ITEM 2' (length=11)
      'type' => null
  5 => 
    array (size=4)
      'nail_id' => int 29
      'code' => string 'NI-3' (length=4)
      'description' => string 'NAIL ITEM 3' (length=11)
      'type' => null
```

---

This is my existing code...

```
$.each(active_items, function(key,value){
  rowTemp1 += "<option value='"+ value['nail_id'] +"'>"+ value['code'] +" "+         value['description'] +"</option>";
      $.each(value['nail_items']  , function(key2,item){
         rowTemp1 += "<option >"+ item['code'] +"</option>";
     });
});
```

Comment: can you create fiddle for this or post array data in form of json rather than object ?

Comment: I couldn't find `nail_id ` and `value['code']` in your array

Comment: check on third array sir

Comment: There's no third array

Comment: `rowTemp1 += "<option value='"+ value['nail_id'] +"'>"+ value['code'] +" "+         value['description'] +"</option>";` should be in second each statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if the key exist in first array if not then search in sub-array.Try below code :

```
var rowTemp1 ="";
$.each(active_items, function(key,value){
      if('nail_id' in value){
         rowTemp1 += "<option value='"+ value['nail_id'] +"'>"+value['code'] +" "+value['description'] +"</option>";
      }else{


           rowTemp1 += "<option >"+ value['nail_items']['code']  +"</option>";

     }
});
```

**[Working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/snt0acxq/1/)**

Comment: this is the result in two different query

Comment: What is the result ?

Comment: <option value="" selected="selected">SelectItem</option>
<option>undefined</option>
<option>undefined</option>
<option>undefined</option>
<option>undefined</option>
<option>undefined</option>
<option>undefined</option>
<option>undefined</option>
<option>undefined</option>
<option>undefined</option>
<option>undefined</option>
<option>undefined</option>
<option>undefined</option>
<option>undefined</option>
<option>undefined</option>
<option value="27">NI-1 NAIL ITEM 1</option>
<option value="28">NI-2 NAIL ITEM 2</option>
<option value="29">NI-3 NAIL ITEM 3</option>
</select>

Comment: lots of undefined value

Comment: Ok above is not JSON , Are you using PHP ? Did you `json_encode` your array before using in JS ?

Comment: im using laravel sir

Comment: Did you really tried my code ? Please check properly . I have put `if else` condition

Comment: yes sir but still other option tag have a value of "undefined"

Comment: Ok Can you tell me what is the result of this code : `console.log(JSON.stringify(active_items));` add this before each statement and check in console

Comment: just like the result with the above code in array 0,1,2

Comment: @PapaKent : Great that I could help !